# How to change make command

Tags: filetype-tex, makeprg

In my `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/tex.vim` I have the following:

```
set makeprg=pdflatex\ -halt-on-error\ -file-line-error\ -synctex=1\ %
set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m
```

however when I run `make` the command that I see is different:

```
:!pdflatex -halt-on-error -file-line-error -synctex=1 test.tex 2>&1| tee /var/folders/gq/vqbg5g255cqf7x_yn8v3tlyc0000gn/T/nvim9VTy4P/7
```

why is `stderr` redirected to `stdin`, what is that second command with `tee` doing, and how do I remove both of them?

I also get this at the end of the compilation (if there were no errors)

```
(1 of 16): This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

and if there's an error I get for example

```
(12 of 16): Undefined control sequence.
```

what does this last line mean, and how can I remove it?

Edit:

Output of `pdflatex -halt-on-error -file-line-error -synctex=1 test.tex` as called from a shell

```
$ pdflatex -halt-on-error -file-line-error -synctex=1 test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdfte
x.map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 16718 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Output of `:make` with `set makeprg=pdflatex\ -halt-on-error\ -file-line-error\ -synctex=1\ %`

```
:!pdflatex -halt-on-error -file-line-error -synctex=1 test.tex  2>&1| tee /var/folders/gq/vqbg5g255cqf7x_yn8v3tlyc0000gn/T/nvim4TX4tu/4
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test.aux) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdfte
x.map}] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 16718 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.

(1 of 16): This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is stderr redirected to stdin,

In order to have both end up in the quickfix list.

> what is that second command with tee doing,

[`man tee`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html). It redirects stdin into a file and into stdout. It's an extremely useful command to log **and** watch the execution of commands that send a massive amount of lines into stdout and/or stderr.

> and how do I remove both of them?

You don't want to. That's what vim `:make` is expecting and needs to in order to populate the quickfix list. See [`:h 'shellpipe'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shellpipe%27).

> > (12 of 16): Undefined control sequence.
>
> what does this last line mean, and how can I remove it?

It means there is an error in your LaTeX file and that you should scroll back to find the exact error line number, and ask in a LaTeX channel.

Comment: That last line is added by `make`, if I call `pdflatex` from a shell I don't see that, that's why I asked. It's there even if there are no errors in the compilation (in that case there's `1 of 16` instead of `12 of 16`).

Comment: In the console, are you also executing `pdflatex` with the halt on first error option? Also, you should have from `1 of 16` up to `16 of 16` messages: there are 16 messages.

Comment: @noibe try `:copen`; vim’s quickfix unfortunately doesnt play too well with multiline error messages (not an issue, just an inconvenience), so that occasionally the helpful bits are one before or one after or such

Comment: @LucHermitte I just updated my question with the shell and make's outputs.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble You mean using `:copen` instead of `:make`?

Comment: @noibe afterwards, to see what errorformat captured in it’s entirety

Comment: > `Press ENTER or type command to continue`

This is just the beginning. And +1 to `:make`+`:copen`.

Comment: @noibe The `(1 of 16)` line is showing you the first line of the `makeprg` output which has been added to your quickfix: because of the way you have configured your `errorformat`, *all* of the output lines are added to the quickfix. (even ones which aren't errors). Have a read of `:help quickfix` and `:help errorformat` to see how all this stuff works, and edit your `'errorformat'` setting if you don't want all these lines in your quickfix.

Comment: @Rich I tried several combinations for `errorformat` but none of them do what I want, which is to hide the line with `(1 of 16)` and the following lines completely. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @noibe, have you tried to start from the one from (La)TeX compiler plugin(s?)?

Comment: @LucHermitte No, but I think what @Rich is describing is how to only add the errors to the quickfix list, instead of all the output of `makeprg`. However, what I'd like is to hide the quickfix message after the `make` output completely, regardless if it's an error or not. If I first call `:copen`, then `:make` doesn't output the first line of the quickfix list, which is what I want.

Comment: @noibe That’s certainly a reasonable thing to ask for. I’d recommend editing your question, because (to me at least) the current wording reads quite differently.

Comment: @Rich I edited the title